# ASIHTTPRequest Monotouch Binding Callback/Event

Tags: binding, event-handling, xamarin.ios, asihttprequest

I am trying to wrap ASIHTTPRequest objective-c library to monotouch and I am stuck on .
The objective-c header file contains

**@property (assign) SEL requestDidFinishSelector;**

and when I use monotouch binding generator it generates

**[Export ("requestDidStartSelector")]**

**Selector RequestDidStartSelector { get; set; }**

This compiles successfully but it does not get called. I want to be able to do

**networkQueue.RequestDidFinish += HandleRequestFinish;**

from my C# code.

Does anyone already have ASIHTTPRequest monotouch binding or guide me on how to hook up callback events?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The selector will only return the handle to the "selector" that you can use.

What you need to do is write your event handler more or less like this:

```
class MyCallbacker {
    public MyCallbacker (Action t) { this.t = t; }

    [Preserve (Conditional=true)]
    [Export ("MyCallBack")]
    void Callback () {
         t ();
    }
}

event RequestDidFinish {
    add {
         requestDidFinishSelector = new Selector ("MyCallback");
         new MyCallbacker (() => value);
    }
}
```